# Why is the 3rd element initialized to a garbage value?

Tags: arrays, c, xcode, initialization, malloc

I am playing around with basic memory allocation with arrays in C using Xcode.

Here's my code:

```
   int *arr; // creating pointer

arr=(int*) malloc(3*sizeof(int)); // allocating memory in heap

printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
printf("%d\n", arr[1]);
printf("%d\n", arr[2]);

int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 5;


arr[0] = a;
arr[1] = b;
arr[2] = c;

printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
printf("%d\n", arr[1]);
printf("%d\n", arr[2]);
```

The output I get is:

0
0
268744246
3
4
5

Why is the 3rd value initialized to 268744246 and not 0 like the first two values?

Comment: By chance. The initial value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` is indterminate.

Comment: And if you *want* it initialized to zeros, use `calloc` instead: `arr = (int*) calloc(3,sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 0):

the function `malloc()` has no effect on the contents of memory being allocated,

Therefore, whatever trash was in the memory allocated is still there after the call to `malloc()`

Note: This code does display undefined behavior due to outputting the contents of un-initialized memory

If  you want the allocated memory to be initialized ( to 0x00 ) then use the function: `calloc()`